# Migrating issue from non ARC to ARC with XCode 5.0.2

Tags: ios, iphone, refactoring, automatic-ref-counting, xcode5

I heard about ARC and I also used it with XCode 4.2 but now a days I have requirement to convert my non-ARC code to ARC format. I have followed some steps to for converting my code to ARC format but somehow i did not get success.

I followed below steps to convert code to ARC:

```
1. “Preferences” -> “General” -> check “continue building after error”.   This step is fundamental to avoid an huge waste of time repeating the next steps every time an error is encountered!
2. “Edit” -> “Refactor” -> “Convert to Objective-C ARC”
3. “Select targets to convert” (check them)
4. Click “precheck” – “Cannot Convert to Objective-C ARC” (Xcode found N issues that prevent conversion from proceeding. Fix all ARC readiness issues and try again.)  You will see this message at least once, because your code contains calls that are forbidden by ARC.
5. Fix them using suggestions (click on errors to open the popup containing the tip). Then repeat from step 1.
6. “Convert to automatic reference counting” window will appear (once issues have been fixed)
7. Click next
8. Review automatic changes
```

I still get errors in all HEADER files of my project regarding @property and @synthesize. I have to manually do all the changes in all HEADER files rather than it can be achieved by automatically just following above steps.

Please help me and let me know if you have any proper solution for this one.

Thanks,

Nilesh M. Prajapati

Answer (score 1):

XCode could not  fix those errors automatically. So you just have to fix them manually before moving on.

Comment: I fix it all appears in .m files but it should be change the syntax automatically as i know that.